# Remove notifications from tray

Tags: android, android-notifications

How can I remove all notifications in the notification tray that were sent by my server when the user clicks on one notifiaction?

I have a chatting-app and the user gets a notification for each message (if the app is not in foreground). When the user clicks on one of those notifications the app will be brought to foreground / will be started. After that has happened, I want all other notifications in the notification bar to disappear as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you dont have to save the ids of all notifications, you can simply call:

```
NotificationManager nManager = ((NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)); 
nManager.cancelAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to cancel a Notification:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

If you have different notifications that need to be canceled you have to save the ids that you used to create the Notification.